# Anti CSRF token functionality still disabled in Bolt\Controller\Backend\Records::edit BOLT CMS

Tags: php, token, csrf, bolt-cms

I have a problem with Bolt CMS. When I add a new record and I save it, I have that message :

"Anti CSRF token functionality still disabled in Bolt\Controller\Backend\Records::edit"

So the content I add is not showed on my view.

Here is my contenttypes and my view for you to show that my code is right (I think) :

```html
pictures:
    name: Pictures
    singular_name: picture
    fields:
        title:
            type: text
            class: large
            group: content
        slug:
            type: slug
            uses: title
        image:
            type: image
        text:
            type: html
            height: 300px
    recordsperpage: 100
    default_status: publish
    sort: -datepublish
```

```html
{% include '_header.twig' %}

<body class="home__bg">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 page__window">
                    <div class="col-md-12 page__window__in">

                        <h2>News</h2>
                        <div class="page__body">
                            {% setcontent adverts = 'pictures/latest/100' %}
                                {% for picture in pictures %}
                                    {{ picture.image }}
                                {% endfor %}    
                            
                        </div><!-- /.marketing__pics -->

                    </div><!-- /.page__window__in -->
                </div><!-- /.page__window -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </section>
    </div><!-- /.container -->



{% include '_footer.twig' %}
```

Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is currently disabled in the master (development) branch as we are working on a refactor. The warning is there to remind us that it's "not done yet"

When it is released as a stable version, it will be re-enaled, so please use a stable version now for any production work.